# Runas Error: Unable to Acquire Password

Tags: visual-studio, command-prompt, windows-7-x64, runas

I'm trying to start visual studio 2010 from command prompt using 'RUNAS' so that I can run it as a different user. I ran the following command:

runas /profile /user:myPCName/SomeUserName "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

My problem is that the commandprompt says "Enter the password for myPCName/SomeUserName:" but I cannot enter the password. I just get the error "RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password"

I googled this for a while and the only answer I found was that I cannot see the password entered, but it is entered anyways, and that I must be typing the wrong password. I'm certain I'm not typing the wrong password.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are so many things your forgot to document:

- what is your logon provider?  Are you attached to a domain?
- are your running this from a UAC elevated command prompt?
- what does the real user name look like?  Is it a system account?
- does the user account actually exist on *your* machine?
- can you logout and logon as that user from your machine?
- does that also work when you disconnect from the network?
- do you actually type this command or is it called from a .bat or script?
- "cannot enter the password", you can't type it or it doesn't like what you typed?

Serverfault.com is a good place to ask about user authentication.

Comment: Wow, you are right that I need to document all of that. I will document it and then post the question on serverfault.com. Thanks!

Comment: I am SO stupid! While I was doing the testing you recommended, I noticed that my syntax was incorrect. I used a "/" in the username instead of a "\" between the domain and username.

Comment: John's tip solved this for me. So easy to use the wrong slash since the command's flags use /, while the domain\user specification needs \. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Actually, I had the same problem with W7 Enterprise (connected to a domain, switching to a locally defined admin user) without UAC elevation with the command:

`runas /user:.\admin cmd.exe`

It did prompt me for the password.

It also worked when I changed it explicitly to:

`runas /user:%COMPUTERNAME%\admin cmd.exe`

Comment: Also worked if don't specify "domain".
runas /user:admin cmd.exe

Comment: Had the same issue using .\admin, also works to use localhost\admin.

Answer (score 7):

I just had this issue.

`runas /username:domain/user cmd` failed

but

`runas /username:domain\user cmd` worked.

So give your slashes a check.